# How can I make waves from the center of a Plane Geometry in Three.JS using the vertex shader?

Tags: three.js, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

I've been learning Three.js and I can't seem to wrap my head around shaders. I have an idea of what I want, and I know the mathematical tools within the GLSL language and what they do in simple terms, but I don't understand how they work together.

I have a plane geometry with a shader material, I want to be able to create waves from the center of the vertex shader, but I am unsure how to accomplish this.

Also, if there is a course or documentation you can provide that could explain simple concepts regarding vertex and fragment shaders that would be great!

This is what I have done so far:

```
varying vec2 vUv;
varying float vuTime;
varying float vElevation;
uniform float uTime;


void main(){
  vec4 modelPosition = modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
  float elevation = sin(modelPosition.x * 10.0 - uTime) * 0.1;
  modelPosition.y += elevation;

  vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * modelPosition;
  vec4 projectedPosition = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

  gl_Position = projectedPosition;

  vuTime = uTime;
  vUv = uv;
  vElevation = elevation;
}
```

I have set up a simple animation using the sin function and a time variable passed to the shader which creates a simple wave effect without the use of noise. I am trying to create a circular wave stemming from the center of the plane geometry.

What I THINK I have to do is use PI to offset the position away from the center while the wave is moving with uTime. To get to the center of the Plane geometry I need to offset the position with 0.5 float.

That is my understanding right now and I would love to know if I'm correct in my thinking or what a correct way is of accomplishing this.

I also am passing the varying variable to the fragment shader to control the color at the elevation.

Thanks for any help you guys provide; I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your shader code, try to change this line

`float elevation = sin(modelPosition.x * 10.0 - uTime) * 0.1;`

to this

`float elevation = sin(length(modelPosition.xz) * 10.0 - uTime) * 0.1;`

You can use either UV coords or position.

```js
let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 10).setLength(10);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

let controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10, "magenta", "yellow"));

let g = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10, 10, 50, 50);
let m = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  wireframe: true,
  uniforms: {
    time: {value: 0},
    color: {value: new THREE.Color("aqua")}
  },
  vertexShader:`
    #define PI 3.1415926
    #define PI2 PI*2.
    uniform float time;
    void main(){
      
      vec3 pos = position;
      pos.z = sin((length(uv - 0.5) - time) * 6. * PI2); 
    
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.);
    }
  `,
  fragmentShader:`
    uniform vec3 color;
    void main(){
      gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.);
    }
  `
});

let o = new THREE.Mesh(g, m);
o.rotation.x = -Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add(o);

let clock = new THREE.Clock();

renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  let t = clock.getElapsedTime();
  m.uniforms.time.value = t * 0.1;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply!

I can gather some information based on what you provided as well, which helps a bunch!

So what I could gather from this is that uv handles where the offset of the shader position is, and position handles the vertex points, is that correct?